# How To accomplish Vue watcher in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, dependencies, react-hooks

I'm trying to accomplish something in React using hooks that I've done many times in Vue but can't seem to figure out how to do it. I want to have a function fire when a certain variable updates, however I want the function to involve other variables as well.

The code below is functionally the exact same, but my linter tells me the react version is wrong because the **res** hook should include input as a dependancy. What if I don't want the console to fire when input is changed, but only when res changes?

Thank you for any help!

```
new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data() {
    return {
      res: false,
      otherVar: 'other'
    }
  },
  watch: {
    res() {
      console.log(this.otherVar);
    }
  },
  created() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setRes();
    }, 2000)
  },
  methods: {
    resResponse() {
      this.res = true
    }
  }
});
```

```
const [res, setRes] = useState(false);
const [input, setInput] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resResponse();
  }, 2000);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(input);
}, [res]);

const resResponse = () => {
  setRes(true);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linter rules and React hook rules in particular exist to prevent common mistakes. If you believe the code is working as intended, a rule can be disabled:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(input);
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [res]);
```

The use of custom hook may prevent the code to be statically analyzed by the linter:

```
const useWatch = (fn, inputs) => useEffect(fn, inputs);
// or just
// const useWatch = useEffect;

...

useWatch(() => {
  console.log(input);
}, [res]);
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to solve the linting. I still worry that maybe there is something I am functionally doing wrong but hopefully not.